# how to add event and event types dynamically to an element in java script not jquery

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add event to element through an function like as follow

```
function addevent(elements,event_n,function_n,param_trs)
    {
          var i = elements.length; 
       while (i--){ 
           function_name=function_n+"(this.getAttribute('"+param_trs+"'))";
           //function_name=function_n ;
           elements[i].addEventListener(event_n,function_name);
          // console.log(function_name);
       }
    }
```

this is giving error :

> TypeError: Value not an object.
>
> at  elements[i].addEventListener(event_n,function_name);

so i can coll them as follow

```
addevent(document.querySelectorAll('tr'),'click','view_details','request_id');
```

to add click event to all tr 
example :

```
<tr request_id="5" onclick="view_details(this.getAttribute('request_id'))" >
```

or

```
<tr request_id="5" onclick="view_details(this)" >
```

how can i do it through function like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is a bad idea to pass function names as string. The same goes for appending code in string format, like `"(this.getAttribute('"+param_trs+"'))"`. This will need to be parsed, much like `eval` does. It is inefficient, and may lead to the [problems related to `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Functions can be passed as arguments, not as strings, but as real function references. Secondly, it would be more appropriate that the event handler function retrieves the attribute value at the moment it executes, not before.

So here is a snippet that presents the idea. The demo will take the attribute `data-inc` to determine with how much a number should be incremented.

```js
function addEventListeners(elements, event_n, attrib_n, func) {
    var i = elements.length; 
    while (i--) { 
        // bind the attribute name as argument to the function.
        elements[i].addEventListener(event_n, func.bind(elements[i], attrib_n));
    }
}

// Demo:
addEventListeners(document.querySelectorAll('span'), 'click', 'data-inc',
    function(attrib_n) { 
        this.textContent = +this.textContent + +this.getAttribute(attrib_n);
    }
);
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid; padding: 2px; background: #C0FFC0 }
```

```html
Click on numbers to change them:<br>
Per 5: <span data-inc="5">0</span> Per 7: <span data-inc="7">0</span>
Per 1: <span data-inc="1">0</span>
Per -1: <span data-inc="-1">0</span>
```